# categorize website based on visitors count

Tags: iis, hosting, web-hosting

my site is having around 300 unique visits/5000 pageviews per day.
i want to know how many unique visits/page views (approx.) a site should have to be called
low , moderate and high traffic website.

also how can i test strength of my website, like how many requests my website can process simultaneously.
http://loadimpact.com/ -- iam looking for some tool like this.

i want these figures to choose a proper webhost as my new project is very big as compared to this one.
Also what are the things we should look for when choosing a web host. Ram and CPU are important for webservers to process requests but most of webhosts never talk of cpu and ram allotted to us. They only provide disk space and daily/monthly allowed traffic in GBS.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache JMeter for stress testing, http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/.